# Ubuntu 17.10 gives error when shutdown

Tags: 17.10

I have MSI laptop cx62 6qd, and every time I shutdown or reboot on ubuntu, always freezes giving the same error, what should I do to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

now, find the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

then save that and close it then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

i would also recommend

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

find the lines like 
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=some number

DefaultTimeoutStopSec=some number
and remove the # in front of them and set the number to 10s

Comment: Thanks for your response and your time, please could you give some brief about the problem please?

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, please If its possible, could you bring some explanation?